How can one convert a .mlpackage Core ML model to a .mlmodel Core ML model?
How can one convert a .mlpackage model to a .mlmodel model?

Example of a .mlpackage Core ML model created on Ubuntu 20.04 (tested with Python 3.10 and torch 2.3.1) with Hugging Face's Exporters lib:
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/exporters.git
cd exporters
pip install -e .
python -m exporters.coreml --model=distilbert-base-uncased exported/ --quantize=float32 

